# Receive 1 byte on disconnected device

Tags: node.js, serial-port

Curiously, I receive 1 byte (content 0) every time no device is connected to my serial port. As soon as the device is connected, the communication works properly, without any issues.

The source ist quite is simple.

```
let serialport = new SerialPort(l_serialport, { 
    baudRate: 19200,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false
});

// data handler
serialport.on('data', (chunk) => {
    let parsedFrame = this.umbparser.ParseReadBuf(chunk);                    

    this.node.log("Parser status: " + parsedFrame.parserState);
    if(parsedFrame.parserState == "finished")
    {
        resolve(parsedFrame);
    }
    else if(parsedFrame.parserState == "processing")
    {
        this.node.log("processing...");
    }
    else {
        resolve(parsedFrame.parserState);
    }
})

// error handler
serialport.on('error', (error) => {
    this.node.log("###error:" + error)
});
    
// send request
serialport.write(umbreq);         

datatimer = setTimeout(() => {
    this.node.log("Data timeout");
    resolve("Data timeout");
}, umb_consts.UMB_TIMEOUT.TIMEOUT_LONG*2);
```

Is this a normal behavior, or is it possibly due to my setup? I am using a USB adapter and developing with NodeJS on a Mac.

Comment: This is probably a hardware problem rather than a software problem. If the pins of a serial port is disconnected, it's in an unknown state and the signals might not be accurate with various factors affecting it like voltage sensitivity, atmosphere, USB to Serial processor model, etc.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I just pulled out another adapter for testing and it didn't show this strange behaviour. Thanks for your support.